# Fluid layout with divs aligned vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I have a fluid layout composed by div having the same width but different height.

My goal (when I resize the screen) is to force any div to be aligned on left side.

With a (hopefully) clear example:

```css
.container {
  border:1px solid silver;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:120px;'>1</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>2</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:130px;'>3</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:90px;'>4</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>5</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:105px;'>6</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:95px;'>7</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:80px;'>8</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:75px;'>9</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:140px;'>10</div>
```

With default screen size I obtain this:

[image]

but my goal is that DIV #7, #8 and #9 would be under div #1, #2, #3

Or with a stretched screen size I would have something like this:

[image]

but my goal is to avoid empty space between div #1 & #4 or #2 & #5.

Which CSS attribute I should use to align div vertically despite the dimension of above one?
Do I have to use flexbox instead?

Answer (score -1):

I think using css grid would be the easiest way to achieve what you're wanting, something like this should do what I think you're asking:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  gap: 5px;
  justify-items: stretch;
}

.container {
  border:1px solid silver;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class='container' style='min-height:120px;'>1</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:100px;'>2</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:130px;'>3</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:90px;'>4</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:100px;'>5</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:105px;'>6</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:95px;'>7</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:80px;'>8</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:75px;'>9</div>
  <div class='container' style='min-height:140px;'>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: does not answer the question exactly ;)

Comment: mhm... this is not exactly what I would like to obtain as min-height is forcing the same height to the tallest div for any row. I would like instead to preserve the div height and put any div having variable height in column one above the other.

Answer (score -2):

It can be easily achieved using flexbox

```css
#mainContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-direction: row;      
    align-items: stretch; 
}

.container {
  border:1px solid silver;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="mainContainer">
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:120px;'>1</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>2</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:130px;'>3</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:90px;'>4</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>5</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:105px;'>6</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:95px;'>7</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:80px;'>8</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:75px;'>9</div>
<div class='container' style='width:100px; height:140px;'>10</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does not answer the question exactly ;)

Comment: How is it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098550/fluid-layout-with-divs-aligned-vertically/77098665?noredirect=1#comment135916559_77098665:~:text=I%20would%20have%20something%20like%20this%3A

Comment: He wanted to achieve mansonry layout which is now linked in the dupplication panel at top of the post ;)

Comment: mhm... this is "more or less" what I would like to obtain but I want to move any div on 2nd row to be adjacent to the one on the top on the same column. Basically removing white vertical space between div.